# Which stats should I add to as an Outlander using Shotguns/Canons?

Tags: torchlight-2

In Torchlight 2, I am a newbie and have not play Torchlight 1 before. It doesn't seem obvious to me which class should add to which stats like diablo 3 does and the more I play it seems there is a lot of versatility to the weapons any class can use.

I did some research on builds for Outlander and it seems that outlanders can go Focus build as well, its shown [here](http://blackrabbit2999.blogspot.com/2012/09/torchlight-2-outlander-focus-build-guide.html). All in all it has made me damn interested in Torchlight 2 with all the builds you can have for each character.

So my question is this, for a Outlander who just solely wants to use canons or shotgonnes which stats should I invest in?

Comment: *Note that the attributes changed since Torchlight 1, so [it does not particularly matter](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84612/should-i-finish-torchlight-before-playing-torchlight-ii?rq=1) to have played it or not.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to build it. Indeed, in Torchlight 2, the stats are not the usual "obvious" (strength for melee, intelligence for mages, etc.).

From [this wiki](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Stats_%28T2%29):

> - **Strength**
>
> Increases all weapon damage
>   Increases damage done by critical strikes
>   *Note that "all weapon damage" includes all weapons, including ranged weapons and weapons that do elemental damage such as staves and wands.*
>
> - **Dexterity**
>
> Increases critical strike chance
>   Increases dodge chance (the chance to evade an attack)
>   Increases fumble recovery (reduces the damage penalty for fumbled attacks)
>
> - **Focus**
>
> Increases maximum mana
>   Increases all elemental damage
>   Increases execute chance (the chance of attacking with both weapons simultaneously when dual wielding similar weapons)
>
> - **Vitality**
>
> Increases maximum health
>   Increases armor
>   Increases block chance (chance to block when using shields)

As an Outlander fighting on range, I assume you will want to maximize your critical damage:

- Strength will increase your damage (raw and critical)
- Dexterity will increase your critical chance

---

Another aspect to keep in mind is the weapon requirement.

- [Shotgonnes](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Shotgonnes_%28T2%29) usually have a stat requirement on dexterity.
- [Cannons](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Cannons_%28T2%29) usually have a requirement on the strength (and sometimes vitality).

So depending on which one you will favor, you can set your attributes more in one or the other direction.

Comment: well i did have another second character which is a berserker and the funny question is that i do want to max out dmg and yet the weapons for the berserker. Claws will require more dexterity yet they crit more, while swords will need more strength and they serves as a steady source of dmg.

So for outlander i am asking whether narrowing down to shotgonnes and canons, which stats will i need to pump?

Comment: @jonleech Cannons are more of an Engineer weapon.  The outlander has no skills that benefit cannons, and many skills require bows / pistols / shotguns.  Most shotguns require dexterity, most cannons require strength.

Comment: oh I did not know that.. sorry this is first of my torchlight game. no wonder i can't find skills to benefit cannon. Thanks +1